# react-admin: Filter with SelectInput shows wrong values

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

The following filter in my `react-admin` app leads to the list showing both records with `status === "active"` and records with `status === "inactive"`. It should show only records with `status === "active"`.

```
<SelectInput 
  alwaysOn 
  source="status" 
  choices={[
    { id: "lead", name: "Lead" },
    { id: "active", name: "Aktiv" },
    { id: "inactive", name: "Inaktiv" },
  ]} 
/>
```

It seems like it includes records with `status === "inactive"` because "inactive" contains the substring "active".

Can I do something about that? Have I misconfigured my `DataProvider`? I am using `react-admin-firebase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-admin-firebase always does fuzzy search when searching for strings:

```
 const isStringSearch = typeof searchValue === 'string';
  if (isStringSearch) {
    return searchThis
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }
```

[Source](https://github.com/benwinding/react-admin-firebase/blob/fb58f58515ee45a43fa92a4acc0f262fe721366a/src/misc/arrayHelpers.ts#L78)

One solution would be to use numbers for `status` instead:

```
<SelectInput 
  alwaysOn 
  source="status" 
  choices={[
    { id: 1, name: "Lead" },
    { id: 2, name: "Aktiv" },
    { id: 3, name: "Inaktiv" },
  ]} 
/>
```

Another solution is to enable lazy loading to search directly against your firebase.